# Linq query using generics & interfaces casting issue

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, generics, interface

I have the following interface:

```
public interface IInactive
{
    bool inactive { get; set; }
}
```

And several objects (entity framework entities) that implement that interface, such as:

```
public class Order : IInactive
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public Guid orderId { get; set; }
    ...
    public bool inactive { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to implement a generic method that can be used to return only "active" records (i.e. inactive == false). It would be called as follows:

```
var query = GetAllActive<Order>();
```

My code for this generic method looks like this:

```
public IQueryable<T> GetAllActive<T>() where T : class
{
    DbSet<T> dbSet = this._db.Set<T>();

    IQueryable<IInactive> query2 = dbSet as IQueryable<IInactive>;
    query2 = query2.Where(w => !w.inactive);
    return (DbSet <T>)query2;

    // System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[Portal.Domain.Entities.Interfaces.IInactive]' to type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1[Portal.Domain.Entities.Order]'.'

}
```

Comment: Do you actually need to make this method generic as your code will always query against an IInactive and hence why not convert your method signature to `public IQueryable<IInactive> GetAllActive()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your code only works with records that inherit from `IActive`, constrain it as such. When you do that, the properties and methods belonging to the interface become available in instances of `T`.

```
public IQueryable<T> GetAllActive<T>() where T : IActive  //Here is the magic
{
    return this._db.Set<T>()
        .Where( w => !w.inactive );
}
```

Isn't that easier?

Comment: Sorry John, in an effort to simplify the question I left out some code.  I cannot do:

public IQueryable<T> GetAllActive<T>() where T : IInactive

because I want the method to be able to accept non-IInactive objects.

Comment: @BillHaack How would you filter classes that don't have the `inactive` property?

Comment: @juharr if (typeof(IInactive).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))

Comment: @BillHaack You know that this is exactly what I originally suggested, right?

Comment: I went ahead and accepted the solution. Even though this was not exactly what I was looking for, it turns out it is probably the best solution to the problem. @madreflection, sorry should have accepted your solution when you offered it up in the previous question!!

Comment: I have what you originally wanted figured out but when I came back I saw that you had accepted this.

Comment: That said, I do think it's better if you can use this solution. The only reason you would need to treat entities that don't implement the interface as implicitly and unconditional active is if there's a layer that deals with all entity types and has to treat them the same.

Comment: @madreflection Thanks for you help. And thanks of your patience with me. I am not a professional programmer. After thinking it though, I came to the same conclusion you came to immediately. Another lesson learned :).

Comment: Those are the best lessons.  :)